# Not able create a new folder using shell script "shell_exec" in php and Shell Script in "/var/www/html" path in Ubuntu

Tags: php, shell, sh, ubuntu-16.04, shell-exec

I'm trying to achieve execute shell scripts create a new folder `/var/www/html/` in this path using by  `shell_exec`in php, web server Apache Server and Ubuntu 16.04

I've tried a list of files in the path `/var/www/html`  in php file using web browser

```
<?php
$output = shell_exec('ls -lart');
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
?>
```

The Output is

```
total 68
-rw-rw-r--  1 ubuntu gitpulluser  573 Jan  6 12:50 .gitignore
drwxrwxr-x  2 ubuntu gitpulluser 4096 Jan  6 12:50 .vscode
drwxrwxr-x 11 ubuntu gitpulluser 4096 Jan  6 12:51 Backendfiles
-rw-rw-r--  1 ubuntu gitpulluser   27 Jan  6 12:51 package-lock.json
-rw-rw-r--  1 ubuntu gitpulluser   17 Jan  6 17:01 pk.sh
-rw-rw-r--  1 ubuntu gitpulluser  243 Jan  6 17:02 myfilename.php
-rw-rw-r--  1 ubuntu gitpulluser  120 Jan  6 17:05 run.php
-rw-rw-r--  1 ubuntu gitpulluser    5 Jan  6 17:06 date.sh
-rw-rw-r--  1 ubuntu gitpulluser  148 Jan  7 11:41 hi.php
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root   root          23 Jan  7 11:48 gitpull.sh
drwxrwxr-x 16 ubuntu gitpulluser 4096 Jan  7 12:25 UIfiles
-rw-rw-r--  1 ubuntu ubuntu        16 Jan  7 12:25 test
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root   root          20 Jan  7 12:27 cgi-test.sh
drwxrwxr-x  8 ubuntu gitpulluser 4096 Jan  7 12:39 .git
-rw-r--r--  1 root   root         144 Jan  7 15:09 shell.php
drwxr-xr-x 15 ubuntu ubuntu      4096 Jan  7 15:09 ..
drwxrwxr-x  6 ubuntu gitpulluser 4096 Jan  7 15:09 .
```

This works fine with no issues, Here I'm facing the challenge **not able to create a folder in the path /var/www/html/**. 
my code is:

```
<?php
shell_exec('sudo mkdir mynewfolder');
?>
```

I'm executing the file from the browser but the folder is not creating. Please help me out from this.
Thanks for advance

Comment: Have you tried running `sudo` solo, as in: on the console? Probably you have to enter a password there?

Comment: Additionally, why not use the built-in ways of creating a folder? That's why PHP contains `mkdir`

Comment: @NicoHaase I want to try to create from the web browser, I tied in the console it's working fine perfect.

Comment: Even if you want to create a folder through the browser, why not use `mkdir` which is a PHP function especially for that?

Comment: I have to  execute a few `git pull` and `git push` command also in this file

Comment: @Kishore : What do you mean by "from the browser"? The browser doesn't run any PHP code.

Comment: @Kishore : What has executing _git_ commands to do with the creation of directories?

Comment: @Kishore : What do you mean by "is not creating"? If mkdir can not create the directory, it writes a message on stderr to explain its failure.

Comment: Is PHP running as user 'ubuntu' and/or in group 'gitpulluser'?

Comment: @user1934428 in console mkdir it will work, I'm trying from PHP `shell_exec` from the web browser used to allow create the folder do perform the task.

Comment: @Sixtus Yes ubuntu is the user and gitpulluser is the group

Comment: @Kishore: You still did not explain what you mean by "from the web browser". A web browser can run JavaScript and Java, but no PHP nor bash. At least I don't know a browser you would be able to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Changed the permission user group and owner permission for the path

```
$sudo chown www-data:www-data -R /var/ww/html
```

After that restart the apache service.

`$suho service apache2 restart`